# Python ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Hey I am trying to run an optimizer on this function. It should return X = 1.5.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo

def f(x):
    # Given a scalar X, return some value (a real number)
    Y = (X - 1.5)**2 + 0.5
    print "X = {}, Y = {}".format(X, Y)
    return Y

def test_run():
    Xguess = 2.0
    min_result = spo.minimize(f, Xguess, method = 'SLSQP', options = {'disp': True})
    print "Minima found at:"
    print "X = {}, Y = {}".format(min_result.x, min_result.fun)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_run()
```

Comment: Is `X` actually a scalar? If not then it's likely that it's forcing `Y` to become a (one-dimensional) numpy array as well.

Comment: Note for CVers: the cause of the issue is the lowercase `x` passed to `f`, but referred to by uppercase `X`.

Comment: Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument to `f()` is a lowercase `x`.  But you refer to uppercase `X` within the function.  Change your function definition to `f(X)` and your code runs without error.

With `f(X)`:

```
test_run()

X = [ 2.], Y = [ 0.75]
X = [ 2.], Y = [ 0.75]
X = [ 2.00000001], Y = [ 0.75000001]
X = [ 0.99999999], Y = [ 0.75000001]
X = [ 1.5], Y = [ 0.5]
X = [ 1.5], Y = [ 0.5]
X = [ 1.50000001], Y = [ 0.5]
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 0.5
            Iterations: 2
            Function evaluations: 7
            Gradient evaluations: 2
Minima found at:
X = [ 1.5], Y = 0.5
```

Comment: If that's really the cause, then the question is a typographical error (which should be closed).

Comment: Yes, good point.  Voting to close.